# Can we say ERC-1155 is the same thing than SFT

Tags: erc-1155, nft

I have understood the differences between Fongible tokens and Non Fongibles tokens (NFT).

I have read a new kind of token called SFT: Semi interchangeable token.
It is supposed to be a mix between FT and NFT.

ERC-1155 is a mix between FT and NFT too, but i do not see people saying ERC-1155 is a SFT.

So are there some differences between ERC-1155 and SFT definition ?

Thanks

Comment: SFT stands for Semi-Fungible Token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example: Suppose a contract mints coupons of 0.1 ETH. Each coupon of 0.1 ETH is identical, so they are fungible.

Now, someone redeems 0.031 ETH from their coupon. Their coupon has now become a non-fungible token, because it is no longer identical to the unused 0.1 ETH coupons.

ERC-1155 allows you to create an SFT, but does not require it. Similarly, you can create an SFT that does not follow the ERC-1155 standard.

You can read the precise ERC-1155 definition here: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155